# Rigify IK Pole Targets Disappearing During Animation

Tags: rigging, rigify, inverse-kinematics, nla-editor, actions

I've been having trouble with my rigify rig where I currently have an action where the IK pole targets disappear completely during the first few frames of the action. I've checked in the rigify properties and they become toggled to 0 for those frames, however there are no keyframes for them at all and so I'm not sure what is causing them to toggle on or off.

Also if I move the same animation to another NLA editor row the IK targets sometimes disappear for the entire duration of that action. All of my other actions are completely fine and don't have this issue so I'm really unsure of what's causing it.

[image]

Comment: Just a few things to note about it, I've abstracted it down to just the rig and the issue can still be seen, if you use the NLA editor at the bottom and watch the "Sprint" action it's fine and the targets are there however moving it into the track below removes them and moving it back up keeps them removed and I'm unsure why. Some bones are hidden as they got pasted strangely when copying.